# Variable in attribute value of XML-literal

Tags: xml, scala, lift

I'm working with LiftWeb, XML and the bind method.

This works:

```
scala> val id = "test"                    
id: java.lang.String = test

scala> <a href={id}>link</a>              
res4: scala.xml.Elem = <a href="test">link</a>
```

but what if I want `<a href="page?param=test">link</a>`?

This doesn't work:

```
scala> <a href="page?param={id}">link</a>   
res5: scala.xml.Elem = <a href="page?param={id}">link</a>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You put the whole thing inside the brackets:

```
<a href={ "page?param=" + id }>link</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer to put it all in curly braces is correct. But don't forget that you need to have a string in the curly braces!

So, you have to write something like (not your example, obviously)

```
<edge label={name} weight={weight.toString} />
```

If you come from a language which converts types for you, it can cost you a few minutes of head scratching before you remember what's wrong, because SBT offers no error message, just underlines it.

Answer (score 0):

Using this , you won't miss the quotes  :  `<a href={s"page?param=$Id"}>link</a>`